# how to set basic value to select box of Bootstrap Smartadmin

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, select, smartadmin

I am working with bootstrap which uses SmartAdmin theme.

It turns all html structure into `<section><div>` struct include `<select><option>`.

So I its output looks like below.

```
<section id="00000001" class="col col-md-6">

        <label class="label">SomeLabel 
            <sapn class="cp_id_text"></sapn>            
        </label>

        <label class="select">
            <div class="select2-container form-hidden-control" id="s2id_00000001" title="" style="width: 100%;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">   <span class="select2-chosen" id="select2-chosen-9">20th Century Fox Film Corporation(00000001)</span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>   <span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></a><label for="s2id_autogen9" class="select2-offscreen"></label><input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-9" id="s2id_autogen9"></div><input type="text" class="form-hidden-control select2-offscreen" id="00000001" name="cp_id" value="" data-init-text="" inputtype="select" title="" maxlength="50" tabindex="-1">
            <script>$("#00000001").select2(selects2Option('00000002','cp_id'));</script>
        </label>    
    <script>

        $("#00000001").attr("maxlength", "50");
    </script>
</section>
```

Since I can not find any `<select>` tags, I can not use selected attribute to set default value.

I can find it via jquery `parent()`, `find()` and so on, but that does not look efficiency. Is there any way I can handle in simple way like `selected` ?

SmartAdmin site says they use select2 api, but they did not mention how to set a value as default.

site : http://192.241.236.31/smartadmin/BUGTRACK/track_/documentation/index.html#!/introduction

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the `select2` demo's you will find **[Programmatic access](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)** area where they have given how to set value on `button` click. The same can be used to set the default value after initialization as below:

```
<select class="js-example-programmatic">
  <option value="one">First</option>
  <option value="two">Second</option>
  <option value="three">Third</option>
</select>
```

**Js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".js-example-programmatic").select2();
     var $example = $(".js-example-programmatic");
     $example.val("three").trigger("change");
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/bL76rajo/)**

Comment: Thanks for answer. However SmartAdmin pluggin change <select> tag to <section>, and <option> to <div>. then what can I do? code above in post is what my select looks like.

Comment: if you provide any sort of fiddle then I can help you more on this!! otherwise it's very difficult to understand!!

Comment: I also added my solution to the post. It has some keywords that I had struggled with. I wish that answer could be a hand to those who also faces this problem :D

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by myself. 
@Guruparasad Rao 's answer was quite help, but I want to talk about how I solved.(Since it is little different)

First, I grabbed the element which binds to select2.

```
target.select2('destroy');
        var data = [
                    {id: 'admin', text: 'admin'}
                    , {id: 'visitor', text: 'visitor'}
                    , {id: 'buyer', text: 'buyer'}];
        target.addClass('col-md-12').select2({data : data, multiple: true});
```

one thing I want to mention is using `id` and `text` key is fixed syntax in select2. The object should contain that keywords.